# Extract terminal child names from a hierarchial OWL file using python (or convert OWL to JSON to make task easier)

Tags: python, owl, owlready

From [this](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/bao) page, I want to click through each sub-node of the tree, and print out all of the terminal child nodes (i.e. a list of all the kits/systems available) (e.g. so in the case below, I would click assay bioassay componant -> assay kit -> print out all the child nodes which are a list of kits):

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology('http://www.bioassayontology.org/bao/bao_complete.owl').load()
print(list(onto.classes()))
onto.save(file = 'onto.test',format='rdfxml')
```

But it doesn't print out the names, it prints out other info to json, e.g.:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0009372">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.bioassayontology.org/bao#BAO_0000264"/>
  <obo:IAO_0000412 rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go.owl"/>
  <oboI:inSubset rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go#goslim_pir"/>
  <oboI:inSubset rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go#gosubset_prok"/>
```

I also tried pronto:

```
import pronto
from pronto import Ontology
ont = Ontology.from_obo_library('/bao.owl')
print(ont)
```

My ideal output is a list of all the terminal child nodes in this tree; or if not possible, just a clear example of how to extract this data to .json so I can then use an XML parser, but in particular, ensuring that the actual names of the kits are in the json file, and not just codes as I got above, if someone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `onto.save` just saves the whole ontology back to disk, not sure what you expected here.

Comment: and to print the hierarchy you first have to compute resp. retrieve the class hierarchy. Just getting all classes won't give you hierarchical information, it's just a set of all classes in the ontology

Comment: Thanks for replying, could you either point to where in the documentation (https://readthedocs.org/projects/owlready2/downloads/pdf/latest/) I should be looking at or provide an example? It's my first time using it. I understand hierarchies generally, that's why I wanted to get it into json format, i'm just struggling with exactly what you say here; I'm unclear what 'compute resp.' means.

Comment: "resp." -> "respectively"

Comment: There is no example online, the idea is start from the top level class, and then recursively get their direct subclasses, then for each subclass their subclass, ... - I guess you get the idea. Getting subclasses for a class is documented here: https://pythonhosted.org/Owlready2/class.html#creating-and-managing-subclasses

Comment: silly me. Thank you, could you point to an example of how to do this with code; I was looking through the docs? Or are you saying that it's not an easy thing to do? is there a line for after get_ontology that's something like 'make_hierarchy_from_ontology' and then 'get_child_nodes', i can't see one.

Comment: No, all I said there is no such example code nor is there such a built-in function like `make_hierarchy`. Getting subclasses of a class is done via `subclasses` method on the class object.